# Calculating the 95th Percentile value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics

I am trying to calculate the 95th percentile point in my table column and am using the `TOP 95 PERCENT` construct. I was wondering if the following approach is correct or if there is a better way of doing the same.

```
SELECT AVG(Value) 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 95 PERCENT WITH TIES Value
    FROM [Sample].[dbo].[numbers]
    ORDER BY Value DESC
) AS NineP
```

Comment: You could look at this: http://web.performancerasta.com/metrics-tips-calculating-95th-99th-or-any-percentile-with-single-mysql-query/

Comment: Maybe [this solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2006/05/15/598372.aspx) will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would get you the (roughly) 97.5 percentile point, because you're taking the average of the top 5%.  You want to `SELECT MIN(Value)`

Comment: Actually I think it would give you >= the 95th percentile.  It would give you the 97.5th if there was an even distribution between 95th and 100th.  But your solution is correct I think.

Comment: I realized this does not work in my case because for my data, it always returns a zero. Would you happen to know how to do this using the `NTILE` function of SQL Server? When I pass NTILE(100), it does it give me the output for percentiles but for the 95th percentile, do I choose the minimum or maximum value in that quartile?

Answer (score 4):

When you get to SQL Server 2012, [PERCENTILE_DISC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231327.aspx) and [PERCENTILE_CONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231473.aspx) functions solve this in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Ntile is where the data is divided into that "tile" where we can think of the tile having a size, and all those sizes being the same for each tile. For your 95th percentile, you want the place where the data is divided for the 95th time. That would be the START of the 95th percentile or the MIN, not the MAX.