# custom aggregate function or equivalent in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

New to SQL Server programming, wanted to see if I can get help on this query.
Say I have a table LatencyInfo

```
DateTime              Latency
2014-01-21 00:00:00    12334
2014-01-21 00:00:00    56384
2014-01-20 00:00:00    1232
2014-01-20 00:00:00    4353
2014-01-19 00:00:00    434343
```

My goal is to find the 95th percentile latency times for each day in the query. So, far I was able to come up with getting 95th percentile for a single date, but I am stuck at aggregating it on dates. I could not use PERCENTILE-CONT because the version of sql server I am hitting does not support this query.

```
select MIN(P.latency) 
from
  (select top 5 PERCENT S.latency as PerLatencyInfo 
    from
      (select convert(varchar(20), datetimefield, 1) as datefield
             ,latency
       from LatencyInfo
       where datetimefield >= '2014-01-21 00:00:00'
      ) as S
    order by S.latency DESC
  ) as P
```

Any help is very appreciated it. I cannot try CLR aggregate here as I cannot install .NET framework on the server.

If I cannot use custom aggregate function, even if I can get help on any other equivalent logic it would be great.

Using Sql Server 11.0.9

Comment: And what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Comments for [Calculating the 95th Percentile value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784299/calculating-the-95th-percentile-value)  post here provide the link to [Oracle's PERCENTILE_CONT implementation using SQL Server 2005 analytic functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2006/05/15/598372.aspx) article.

Comment: Using Sql Server 11.0.9206

Comment: @user3167619 cool, the old skool way: 11.0 :)

Comment: @PM77-1 the article is very good and informative. Thank you it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 or higher, you can use window functions and do the same thing:

```
select cast(datetime as date) as thedate, latency
from (select pli.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(datetime as date) order by latency) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by cast(datetime as date)) as daycnt
      from PerLatencyInfo
     ) pli
where seqnum = 0.95 * daycnt;
```

The column `seqnum` just enumerates the values each day from lowest latency to highest latency.  The value `daycnt` is the total on the day.  The 95th percentile is calculated in the `where` clause.

Some notes.

- SQL Server 2005 doesn't support `cast( as date)`, but there are other mechanisms such as your `convert()`.
- This doesn't do interpolation between values.

Comment: You mean SQL Server 2008 or higher then? Because in your notes you say  `CAST( AS DATE)` is NOT working for 2005?

Comment: @NickyvV The analytic/window functions are available in 2005+, `DATE` in 2008+.

Comment: @NickyvV . . . I just think that `cast(date as date)` is the best syntax, but there are other methods.  The window function I use, as mentioned in the other comment, are available for SQL Server 2005 onward.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the **NTILE** windowed function.

In the below example I have used **NTILE(20)**, This splits the rows returned into 5% blocks and assigns a number from 1 to 20 for each block.

```
SELECT   [DateTime], Latency
FROM    ( SELECT    [DateTime], 
        Latency, 
        NTILE(20) OVER ( PARTITION BY cast([DateTime] as date) ORDER BY Latency ASC) Top5
          FROM      latencyInfo
        ) x
WHERE   Top5 = 1
```

I **partitioned the rows on DateTime** so that it will perform the NTILE function on each date and **ordered by Latency Ascending** (smallest goes in the top NTILE).

Then all I have to do is select everything that is in the top percentile. (**Where Top5 = 1**)